# Odoo Cron with field increment?

Tags: python, cron, odoo

How can I create a cron job in Odoo, that is executed every end of the months and all it does is increment a field by 2.5?

Answer (score -1):

**In the xml:**

```
<record forcecreate="True" id="ir_cron_any_name"
            model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Your String</field>
            <field eval="False" name="active" />
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">months</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name='active'>false</field>
            <field name="False" eval="True" />
            <field name="model" eval="'model.name'" />
            <field name="function" eval="'python_function_name'" />
            <field name="args" eval="'()'" />
        </record>
```

**In Python:**

```
@api.model
def python_function_name(self):
    Your function goes here
```

Comment: You can configure in the front end.

Comment: Don't always try to discourage people@CZoellner

Comment: I don't discourage people. He asked for a special requirement and you answered with the most simple solution without even saying/writing anything about the special core requirement of his question. I wouldn't downvote the answer, when there was a clear hint, that it does not answer how to configure the cron for triggering at every months end.